# Java - Algorithm to find most connected numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a problem but can't seem to find anyone else that has tried to do a similar task. I have a grid of numbers in an int array grid[][]

```
2 5 1 0 8 0 8
2 1 0 9 7 2 4
3 6 2 3 4 9 7
3 3 3 4 7 8 9
3 3 1 2 3 1 4
9 7 4 1 2 3 4
```

I need a simple algorithm to find where there is the most numbers connected by only going up, down, left and right. So in the example above it would find the 3 at index [2][0].

I know the problem could be solved by simply doing if statement and loop after loop but that would be very repetitive but was wondering if there is an easier way of doing this?

Any help is appreciated, this is for a game I am creating. Thank you :)

EDIT: to help clear this problem up.

```
2 5 1 0 8 0 8
2 1 0 9 7 2 4
3 6 2 3 4 9 7
3 3 3 4 7 8 9
3 3 1 2 3 1 4
9 7 4 1 2 3 4
```

the method would return 0,2 as the answer because it would find that

```
3
3 3 3
3 3
```

has the most adjacent numbers

another example,

```
2 5 1 0 8 0 8
2 1 0 9 7 2 4
3 3 3 3 4 6 7
1 0 3 4 7 4 9
3 3 3 2 3 1 6
9 7 4 1 8 4 6
```

the full find would be

```
3 3 3 3
    3
3 3 3
```

Thanks for all the answers so far, Depth first search looks interesting but can only find information on tree style searches so far.

Comment: what dos 'the most numbers connected' mean?

Comment: Try flood fill, removing each visited entry. Trivial recursive implementation without stack size optimizations should do.

Comment: What does "most numbers connected"? Do you mean the cell that has the highest sum of 4-adjacent cells?

Comment: So...how would you approach it with the if statement and loop?  Do you have the code that you've tried?

Comment: Why **3** in this example? I don't understand this.

Comment: I think you could solve it using recursion...

Comment: recursion and the Visitor pattern... :)  agree with others - you should post some code before this one gets closed.

Comment: Per his example, if you count down "0, 1, 2" from the top left and then 0 over, you'll find that there are three 3s in a vertical column.  And I'm guessing that at 3,0 there's a row of three 3s that would also satisfy what he's looking for.

Comment: Sorry if it isn't clear. What I mean is that it would go through each number so that it would start at index 0,0 any numbers adjacent (above,below,left,right) to it in the grid and if it finds any, then it would check any numbers adjacent to that number and so on until it finds the longest chain of numbers. Hope this can clear it up!

Comment: I recommend using a depth-first search in order to visit every number in the grid. However, you might want to consider creating a class to represent each cell in a grid. Every object instance of this class could have 8 members to represent its possible connections. Each instance could also have a member to record whether it has been visited or not. It might make your recursion more semantically meaningful.

Comment: Also, the number isn't for a sum or anything math related it is simply an ID of something else.

Comment: @Marvo: Thanks.  Seems like there are 6 answers at (2,0), (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (4,0).  Does the OP want all 6 answers, or just the first occurrence?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am only looking for the first occurrence.

Comment: @mattxo: Ok.  You only have to look right and down at each position.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Not so, because once you have moved down or right, there could be an occurence left or up after then moving left in the algorithm if that makes any sense lol

Comment: @mattxo: You would have found those occurrences already, since you're going from left to right and top to bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work with small tweaks. I have not run it myself, but the concept should be clear. Can also be optimized since the same spaces may be evaluated multiple times.

```
public class FindConsecutiveNumbersInGrid {

public static int[][] grid = new int[][]{
    {2, 5, 1, 0, 8, 0, 8},
    {2, 1, 0, 9, 7, 2, 4},
    {3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 7},
    {1, 0, 3, 4, 7, 4, 9},
    {3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 6},
    {9, 7, 4, 1, 8, 4, 6}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxFound = 0;
    int[] maxFoundPos = new int[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            boolean[][] foundGrid = new boolean[grid.length][grid[0].length];
            findConsecutive(i, j, foundGrid);
            int found = getFound(foundGrid);
            if (found > maxFound) {
                maxFound = found;
                maxFoundPos[0] = i;
                maxFoundPos[1] = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(maxFoundPos[0] + " " + maxFoundPos[1]);
}

public static void findConsecutive(int i, int j, boolean[][] foundGrid) {
    foundGrid[i][j] = true;
    if (i < grid.length - 1 && grid[i][j] == grid[i+1][j] && !foundGrid[i+1][j]) {
        findConsecutive(i+1, j, foundGrid);
    }
    if (i > 0 && grid[i][j] == grid[i-1][j] && !foundGrid[i-1][j]) {
        findConsecutive(i-1, j, foundGrid);
    }
    if (j < grid[i].length - 1 && grid[i][j] == grid[i][j+1] && !foundGrid[i][j+1]) {
        findConsecutive(i, j+1, foundGrid);
    }
    if (j > 0 && grid[i][j] == grid[i][j-1] && !foundGrid[i][j-1]) {
        findConsecutive(i, j-1, foundGrid);
    }
}

public static int getFound(boolean[][] foundGrid) {
    int found = 0;
    for (boolean[] foundRow : foundGrid) {
        for (boolean foundSpace : foundRow) {
            if (foundSpace) found++;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

}

This prints correctly "2 0".

Comment: Just implemented this and doesn't work fully. seems to only look down? - sorry didn't see your edit. Thanks for the try though!

Comment: Will try to implement it when I got the time, if it has not been answered yet.

Comment: The reason it did not work was some syntax errors. I have updated it to work, but it is still buggy since it still find the same space twice. You have to remember found spaces and not count them twice.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you so much! very simple and clean code. This is very close but isn't quite correct like you said.

Comment: Well, we can't do it all for you ;)

Comment: Ok you win. Have edited the code to be (hopefully) completely correct. :)

Answer (score 2):

in fact,you want to find all [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29).
BFS and [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) are famous algorithm about this.and for this problem you can use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).so you assume for each number you have a vertex.and this vertex connected by only going up, down, left and right that their numbers are equal.repeat DFS until all vertex will mark.now find a component which it has a maximum number in this graph.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the largest flood-fillable area, then you can use a standard [flood-fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), counting the number of nodes you fill, while filling them with a value which indicates that they should not be visited again. This will be `O(n2)` for a `n x n` array, which should be optimal.

If you want the longest sequence, as opposed to the largest area, then you would have to search for the longest Hamiltonian path within each flood-fill area. Unfortunately, you're out of luck, according to [Hamilton Paths in Grid Graphs (1982)](http://epubs.siam.org/action/showAbstract?page=676&volume=11&issue=4&journalCode=smjcat) by Alon Itai, Christos H. Papadimitriou, and Jayme Luiz Szwarcfiter. I couldn't find a non-paywall version, but the abstract seems clear enough. (Of course, the fact that a problem is NP-complete doesn't mean that its unsolvable. Maybe your N is small enough to make it practical.)

Answer (score 0):

> I need a simple algorithm to find where there are the most consecutive numbers connected by going down and to the right.

A simple algorithm is to loop through the rows and columns, looking for the longest sequence down and to the right.

Since you only want the first occurrence, you don't have to look left or up.

You can break the loops when you get to indices that are less than the longest string found.  In other words, once you find a string of 3 characters, you don't have to loop through the last two columns and last two rows.

However, it's almost as quick, and much easier, to loop through the entire matrix.

In your example, you'll find two strings of 3 threes, one at (2,0) and one at (3,0).  You would just take the first answer as your final answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying but this wouldnt find the best answer because it would need to look left and up as in example 2 in the edit i put above. Thanks for your help and sorry my comment explained the problem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can formulate this as a dynamic programming problem

Calculate the number of adjacent paths that are ascending
    path[i][j] = 1 for all i,j

```
for i=0;i<n 
  for j=0;j<n
     for dirx, diry in [(1,0),(0,1) ... etc ... ]
        if arr[i+dirx][j+diry] = arr[i][j] + 1
           path[i+dirx][j+diry] += path[i][j]
```

The answer will be `max(path[i][j])` for all i,j.

Or recursively, if you prefer

```
   for i,j<n
       go(i,j)

   def go(i,j)
        if path[i][j]>0 return path[i][j]
        ret = 1;
        for dirx, diry in [(1,0),(0,1) ... etc ... ]

            if arr[i+dirx][j+diry] = arr[i][j] + 1
               ret = max(ret, go(i+dirx,j+diry))

        return ret
```

Comment: not sure how to implement for dirx, diry in ..., any idea how this could be done in java? it seems you know how to solve it :) - is that python? i am not very skilled with python :(

Comment: it's just pseudocode - dirx diry is just the directions in a coordinate system [0,1],[-1,0]... etc.  In java you could iterate over a 2d array like `int[][] = new int[4][2]{ [0,1] ....}

Comment: Ahhh so in Java it would be a for loop within a for loop. Thank you, I will try implement it now.

Answer (score 0):

First find a non-visited cell, and start recursion. 
disclaimer: This is not java, it's pseudo C without most declarations and headers. C is anyway much easier to convert to java... Use a global or a class member for the count if necessary.

To make things easier, surround your N*N array by guards.

```
    // with -1 -1 -1 -1 
    //      -1  x  x -1
    //      -1 -1 -1 -1

for (i=N+2;i<(N+2)*(N+1);i++) { // exact starting and ending locations are disclosed
  if (k=array[i]!=-1) {
      j=1;
      flood_fill(array,i,k,&j);
      if (j>max) { max=j; max_number=k; }
  }
}

#define UP -(N+2)
#define DOWN (N+2)
#define LEFT -1
#define RIGHT 1

int flood_fill(int *array, int position, int value_to_compare, int *count)
{
    // for each direction UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT 
    static const int directions[4]={UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT];
    int t;
    for (t=0;t<4;t++)
    if (array[position + directions[t]]==value_to_compare) {
        array[position + directions[t]] = -1;
        *count+=1;
        flood_fill(array, position+directions[t], value_to_compare, count);
    }
}
```