# Efficient grouping of nodes that can reach each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, d3.js, underscore.js

I have some graph data, where the edges between nodes are on this form:

```
var edges = [
    ["A","B"], ["B","C"], ["B","D"], ["E","F"], ["E","G"]
];
```

What is the most efficient (running time) way to group the nodes that can reach each other? In my case:

```
[["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G"]]
```

I am looking for a solution in pure javascript, or possibly by use of d3.js, underscore.js or jQuery. Pseudocode is also fine :)

---

**UPDATE:** Because some people have proposed this to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394534/java-algorithm-to-find-most-connected-numbers) I will explain what I am using this for.

I have a number of 2D-points (probably less than 500) and I want to group points that are close to each other. First I do [delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) where I get a planar graph, I add the [euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) as weights on the edges and use [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) to make a [minimum spanning tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree) (MST). I remove all edges from the MST that are to long. Now I end up with a number of edges (as described above) that I want to process and find the clusters. When I have the clusters I will make convex hulls of them to visualize it.

So it is an undirected graph. The only thing an edge tells me, is that the two vertices it connects will be in the same cluster.

Even if the the number of points might be low, the running time is important, because this will be calculated on every mousemove.

---

**SOLUTION:** Thanks for the suggestions. For sake of completeness, here is the solution I came up with:

```
// Make a cluster for each vertex
var clusters = _.map(vertices, function(node) { return [node]; });

while(edges.length > 0) {

    var edge = edges.pop();
    var vertexA = edge[0],
        vertexB = edge[1];

    var cA = _.filter(clusters, function(cluster) {
        return _.contains(cluster, vertexA);
    });

    var cB = _.filter(clusters, function(cluster) {
        return _.contains(cluster, vertexB);
    });

    if(_.union(_.difference(cA,cB) , _.difference(cB,cA) ).length > 0) {
        clusters = _.without(clusters, cA[0], cB[0]);
        clusters.push(_.union(cA[0], cB[0]));
    }
}

return clusters;
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I want to find all "clusters" of nodes that can reach each other.

Comment: Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make a list of nodes. Mark each as unvisited (white)
2. Starting with the first node mark it as grey. Do a [breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or a [depth first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) only processing white nodes. When you conclude with the parent, mark it as black.
3. All the black nodes in your list are connected. You can remove them from the list you created in (1), and do this again for find the next set of connected nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a directed graph? or undirected graph?

If its undirected graph, You can use bfs/dfs.

1. Go through the list of vertices that are not visited.
2. Start from a vertex which has an edge and the other vertex not yet visited. do bfs/dfs. Keep track of nodes being visited in the current traversal
3. Group the nodes you visited in current traversal.
4. Go to 1.

Complexity will be same as that for BFS/DFS.